# Replace multiple if conditions(null checks) and some block of code within each block in Java 11

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a list of say vehicles that each contain types of vehicles like car, bus, truck etc. So the code I currently have is as shown below

```java
vehicles.stream().foreach(vehicle -> {
    if(null != vehicle.getCar())
    {
       doSomething();
    }
    if(null != vehicle.getBus())
    {
       doSomething();
    }
    if(null != vehicle.getTruck())
    {
       doSomething();
    }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this in Java 11?

Comment: I might consider having an `enum`, maybe something like `enum Type { CAR, BUS, TRUCK }`, then you could just make use of `switch` statement but's not going to remove the need to "identify" each vechical

Comment: Maybe change `doSomething();` to `doSomething(Vehicle vehicle);`  then call as `doSomething(vehicle.getCar()); doSomething(vehicle.getBus()); doSomething(vehicle.getTruck());`

Comment: If you used the `enum` approach, you could then do something like `vehicles.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Vehicle::getType));` which would group the `vehicles`s by their type - see [Guide to Java 8 groupingBy Collector](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) for more details

Comment: Can you briefly explain what `doSomething()` does? Are you sure that you can't benefit from the polymorphism, and there's a real need to discriminate between subtypes of Vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow Liskov Substitution. If you don't know what it is, please read [this](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/).

First of all, you must declare "Vehicle" as an interface. This interface can have some essential methods that your inherited objects must implement. For example, all vehicles must start their engine.

```java
public interface Vehicle {
    
    public void startEngine();

}
```

Know any vehicle that you want can implement this interface and its method/methods:

```java
public class Car implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void startEngine() {
        // Turn on the gasoline engine
    }

}
```

```java
public class Truck implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void startEngine() {
        // Turn on the diesel engine
    }

}
```

So in your case, you can do something like this whit your array of vehicles:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(new Car());
        vehicles.add(new Truck());
        vehicles.foreach(vehicle -> {
            vehicle.startEngine();
        });
    }

}
```